# FiddlerCore + autoresponder?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, fiddler

I have just discovered FiddlerCore (a .NET API to automate some Fiddler functionality) and I would like to use this in combination with Fiddler's autoresponder to run some automated testing given a set of predefined request-->response sessions (which is how autoresponder works, I believe).

I cannot figure out how to set this up with FiddlerCore. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in the forums: http://groups.google.com/group/httpfiddler/browse_thread/thread/8075b029d3b66720

While your application can use FiddlerCore to return 
responses of your choosing, the current public FiddlerCore bits don't 
have the ability to read .SAZ files. Fiddler depends on Xceed's Zip 
libraries for opening SAZ files, but those libraries are not free (MS 
itself has a site license, which is how Fiddler itself may use 
them).

A future version of FiddlerCore will likely use one of the opensource 
ZIP libraries from CodePlex, at which point FiddlerCore will be able 
to open and process a SAZ File, but you'll still need to write the 
code that actually matches a given request to a previously loaded 
response yourself-- the "AutoResponder" code is a part of Fiddler, not 
FiddlerCore.