# AutoResponder in FiddleCore

Tags: fiddler

is it possible to develop an AutoResponder like actions for FiddleCore?
in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147385/fiddlercore-autoresponder) it said that we should wait for new version of Fiddler. it's out. what now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can write an AutoResponder-like feature using FiddlerCore. The FiddlerCore package includes a class that allows you to load a .SAZ traffic archive capture.

You can then play back the responses that you loaded by hooking the BeforeRequest method, and using the oSession.utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer() method.

You'd check the URL and/or other data to figure out which response to return, and copy the response data out of the loaded session into the new response.